# Unattended Linux Mint Install

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, preseed, ubiquity

I am trying to create a Linux Mint 17.1 development box (in a virtual machine) but I'd like to automate the process.

The instructions on how to perform an unattended installation are pretty out of date:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150921124244/http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/54

I've had no success using a preseed.cfg file. I would usually get stuck at some part of the Ubiquity install screen.

I was wondering if anyone has had any success in bringing up a Linux Mint VM or if there's someway of figuring out how to determine what values to put into the preseed.cfg file so that a fully automated installation can be achieved.

Comment: You could do one manual installation, make an image, and then just clone the image and run a provisioner (e.g., a shell script).

Comment: were you able to get passed the first Ubiquity Welcome/language screen?